# Stop current CSS transition animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

In jQuery, when there's the handy .stop() function when you can have an animation triggered before the last animation is complete. Is there a similar way to do this for CSS animations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [animation-play-state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-play-state)

```
animation-play-state: paused;
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Cvw5Z/